# Smart query syntax for singe values in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been trying to find an alternative to the `for (<query>) loop <statements> end loop;` syntax in PL/SQL for single values. The reason is **purely** one of code maintainability and readability point of view, ie I want to get rid of the declaration as the `for (<query>) loop <statements> end loop;` does.

You can do the following:

```
declare
   id myTable.id%type:= 4;
   result myTable%rowtype;
begin
   select mt.* into result 
     from myTable mt
     where mt.id = id;

   <do something with result>
end;
```

But I believe the below way is cleaner and would like something similar for single values with exceptions being thrown on `NO_DATA_FOUND` and `TOO_MANY_ROWS` as usual with `select into`:

```
for result in (select * from myTable mt where mt.id = id) loop
  <do something with result>
end loop;
```

Just to repeat myself, the important part is maintainability, so getting rid on having to declare a a variable which might only be used in a short scope is vital. If `closures` or other forms of scoping is needed does not matter, performance does not matter (up to a factor of roughly 1000), code readability and maintainability does.

What I am wondering is if you know a way which is better or cleaner in your taste than either the for loop with extra check for possible no data (`TOO_MANY_ROWS` is usually avoided with constraints so that check can be avoided) or the `select into` statement which requires a declared variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here.  Are you asking whether the `select into` syntax improves maintainability?  Are you asking whether there is a third approach that is better than both of the options you provide?  If you want to avoid declaring the local variable `result`, how would you refer to the value that is returned in the `<do something>` block (which, I'm guessing, is multiple statements)?  Can we suggest refactoring the `select` statement into a function that is called (possibly multiple times) below?

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry if I am unclear, I'll edit. What I'm asking is basically if there is a syntax or other construction which might allow me to use tighter syntax, like the for loop with query, which works just as `select into`?

Comment: PL/SQL is a err... a bit old-fashioned and verbose language. The best you can do here to limit variable scopes is to use nested anonymous blocks and functions.